# How to Find ListBox1.SelectedItem in other ListBox2 Items

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listbox

I want to filtering Items of one list and show result into another list. when i fill first ListBox by calling `.Items.Add()` it works fine. but when i fill it by a table by `.DataSource` property of it, it works fine too but i can not save `.selectedItem` of first list and select it in second listbox.

I have ListBox1 in my form and fill it by a table returned from database on `Form_Load` event.

i also have a button that write on `Button_Click` event:

```
            //saving selected item by user in the first List
        object selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem;

        // filtering rows in the first List and showing into second List
        DataTable dtable = (DataTable)listBox1.DataSource;
        var x = (from drow in dtable.AsEnumerable()
                 where drow["name"].ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToUpper())
                 select drow).AsEnumerable();
        listBox2.DataSource = null;
        if (x.Count() > 0)
            listBox2.DataSource = x.CopyToDataTable();
        listBox2.DisplayMember = listBox1.DisplayMember;
        listBox2.ValueMember = listBox1.ValueMember;

        //setting the selected item in the second list
        if (selectedItem != null && listBox2.Items.Contains(selectedItem))
            listBox2.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
```

but in result, ListBox2 wont select selected item in ListBox1 because last `if` would not be true.

please tell me what is wrong. thanks

Comment: Before If statement, try calling the DateBind method on listBox2.

Comment: @Adeel ListBox2 has not this method. my application is windows base

Comment: @ahoo, I'm sorry, I can't understand your english, are you saying that when you select some items in list box 1, that you want the same items in list box 2 to be selected if available?

Comment: @Nick Yes. of course textbox1 has not Multi Selection

Comment: @ahoo, Didn't realize this was winforms, I honestly have no idea how to achieve this in winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
 //setting the selected item in the second list
 if (selectedItem != null)
  listBox2.SelectedItem = (
    from item in listBox2.Items.Cast<DataRowView>()
    where item[listBox2.ValueMember].ToString() == ((DataRowView)selectedItem)[listBox1.ValueMember].ToString()
    select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the use of method CopyToDataTable. If you read it's summary:

> Returns a System.Data.DataTable that contains copies of the System.Data.DataRow objects, given an input System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable object where the generic parameter T is System.Data.DataRow.

This implies that at the time of your 'if' comparison listBox2.Items contains different instances (with same information) than contained in listbox1.DataSource - this includes listbox1.SelectedItem and therefore listbox2.Items never contains listbox1.SelectedItem.

Answer (score 0):

The selectedItem object of listBox1 will not be in listBox2. This is due to the line listBox2.DataSource = x.CopyToDataTable() which creates a new list. The two listbox are pointing to the same datasource but they are represented in each listbox with completely different ListItems.

A solution to this is to just iterate the listBox2 and search for the selected item.